# How to get how many days a week number has

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im making a ganttchart where user can choose the startdate and end date. And the gantt chart should display the week numbers following the iso standard. There are two situations, the start week number or last week number may not have 7 days, it can be less (example 1st january 2023, which is week 52, in this case week 52 only has 1 day).

this is what i have been trying so far:

```
  const startDate=moment(this.chartData.startDate);
    const endDate = moment(this.chartData.endDate);
    const weeknum = Math.ceil(endDate.diff(startDate, 'weeks', true));

    for (let i = 0; i <= weeknum; i++) {
      const weekStart = moment(startDate).add(i, 'weeks');
      const weekEnd = moment(endDate).add(i, 'weeks');
      const weekNumber = weekStart.isoWeek(); 
      const daysInweek = endDate.diff(weekStart, 'days')+1;

      this.weeks.push({
        weekNumber: weekNumber,
        weekDays: daysInweek
      });
    }
        console.log(this.weeks)
```

but the problem here is that it doesnt calculate right. if we go by the example where the start date is 1st janaury 2023. It starts counting that week 52 has 365 days, week 1 has 358 and so on. how do i fix this so that week 52 has 1 day, week 1 has 7 days...?

english is not my first language, but i tried to explain the problem as best as i could.

Comment: I don't fully understand your issue, but you can check that day of the week the first week starts. And count the days starting from it: if it starts with Friday (let's say), you know that the week has 3 days and so on. Same for the last week. Just keep in mind that are regions where the first day of the week is Sunday, and regions where the first day of the week is Monday. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```js
function getWeeksAndDays(date) {
  const weeks = [];
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.getMonth();
  let firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
  let lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
  let weekNum = getISOWeekNumber(firstDay);

  while (firstDay.getMonth() === month) {
    const daysInWeek = Math.round((lastDay.getDate() - firstDay.getDate()) / 7) + 1;
    weeks.push({ weekNum, daysInWeek });
    firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 7);
    lastDay.setDate(lastDay.getDate() - 7);
    weekNum++;
  }

  return weeks;
}

function getISOWeekNumber(date) {
  const d = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()));
  const dayNum = d.getUTCDay() || 7;
  d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - dayNum);
  const yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1));
  return Math.ceil(((d - yearStart) / 86400000 + 1) / 7);
}
```

And some unit test:

```js
describe("getWeeksAndDays", () => {
  test("returns correct results for February 2023", () => {
    const date = new Date("2023-02-01");
    const expected = [
      { weekNum: 5, daysInWeek: 7 },
      { weekNum: 6, daysInWeek: 7 },
      { weekNum: 7, daysInWeek: 7 },
      { weekNum: 8, daysInWeek: 7 }
    ];
    const result = getWeeksAndDays(date);
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
  });

  test("returns correct results for December 2023", () => {
    const date = new Date("2023-12-01");
    const expected = [
      { weekNum: 48, daysInWeek: 7 },
      { weekNum: 49, daysInWeek: 7 },
      { weekNum: 50, daysInWeek: 7 },
      { weekNum: 51, daysInWeek: 7 },
      { weekNum: 52, daysInWeek: 7 }
    ];
    const result = getWeeksAndDays(date);
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
  });

  test("returns correct results for January 2022", () => {
    const date = new Date("2022-01-01");
    const expected = [
      { weekNum: 53, daysInWeek: 1 },
      { weekNum: 1, daysInWeek: 7 },
      { weekNum: 2, daysInWeek: 7 },
      { weekNum: 3, daysInWeek: 7 },
      { weekNum: 4, daysInWeek: 7 }
    ];
    const result = getWeeksAndDays(date);
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```